# How to use a varible to open a file

Tags: python, file, variables, python-3.4

I am trying to **open a file using a variable**, I can do this with an if statement to find what file to open but it would be 10 times easier to just have it use a variable to find out what to open. The code bellow is not the full code but it is what I kind of want to do. Sadly this attempt did not work as well as I hoped but it gives you an idea of what it will do.

```
name = "Jacob"
door = "me"
print (name)

File = open (name".txt","r")#opens the Little file
Little = []#creates Little list
Little = File.read().splitlines()#adds what is in Little file to Little list
print (Little)
```

Comment: you should the 'with' keyword in python for file objects because it closes the file at the end. @igon has an example on one of the answers below. It is good practice.

Comment: You shouldn't use Uppercase names for variables. Why does your attempt "not work as well" as you hoped? Did you get an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supposed to be:

```
File = open (name + ".txt","r")#opens the Little file
```

From what I gather anyway.

Forgot the `+` between `name` and `".txt"`
Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
name = "Jacob.txt"
with open(name,'r') as f:
    content = [ line for line in f]
    print content
```